# asp.net download controller client from server mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download

When I use `@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Generate", "Report"))` and press submit button, then the byte file is opened in end of my page

When I use Export

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Generate")" class="btn btn-primary">Export2</a>
```

then the file is downloading and saving in default folder DOWNLOADS.  So what is the difference between submit and a href???

```
public FileContentResult Generate()
        {
            byte[] resultee2 = new byte[12];
            return new FileContentResult(resultee2, "text/plain") { FileDownloadName = "myfile.txt" };
        }
```

And how can I create downloading file to folder after submitting form?

I have a form with fields, then I press submit button and values from fields are being send to server, server is generating byte array and then server is responding that byte array then controller has this byte array and then I want to convert this byte array to text and send to client as Download File.

Comment: The ajax is happening in the background so the browser does not directly interact with the response. You would need to save the file yourself. The link approach is being directly managed by the browser so when the response returns, it sees that it is a file and processes it as such

Comment: You would need to save the file yourself. What do you mean by this?

Comment: Or how to return  new FileContentResult(resultee2, "text/plain") { FileDownloadName = "myfile.txt" }; to memory, and then create next button On click = download(file from memory)

Answer (score 0):

Form file downloads over AJAX do not always function like opening a file from a hyperlink click or after a standard form post action.  What I've done in the past is define an action:

```
public ActionResult Download(long id)
{
   //get record info
   return File(fileStream, "application/pdf");
}
```

I was working with PDFS in this example (note the browser by default, would open in a new tab and not prompt to download directly).  And access this action via javascript:

```
window.open("Download?id=" + id, "_blank");
```

This will call the download option and return the contents.  Note that this requires using some persistence mechanism, like storing the file on disk or in the database, or recreating the file from data in the database.

You also have more control if you use jQuery's $.ajax method because you have more control over the request and response, and could possibly return file data back through the AJAX call response...